# Jtable Select row and columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to select a row and column of jtable's cell and print the value, i do this in `public void changeValue()`,as shown below, but i got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source) at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source) at ShopManagement.ShowEmployee.changeValue(ShowEmployee.java:81) at ShopManagement.ShowEmployee.(ShowEmployee.java:74) at ShopManagement.ShowEmployee.main(ShowEmployee.java:87)`

maybe,have i to implement a mouselistener that is used to check the current position of cursor in jtable?

if so,how can I change the code?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import DataBaseConnectionSingleton.Connection;
import DataBaseConnectionSingleton.CreationStatement;

public class ShowEmployee extends JFrame {
public JTable table = new JTable();

public ShowEmployee() {
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

try {

    Connection.getConnectionInstance();
    Statement st = CreationStatement.getCreationStatementInstance();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

    // Get column names

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
    }

    // Get row data

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
        }

        data.addElement(row);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

// Create table with database data

table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null) {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }

        return Object.class;
    }
};

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
changeValue();
}

public void changeValue() {

int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
String s=(String) table.getValueAt(rowIndex,colIndex);
System.out.println("INNERTABLE:" + rowIndex + "*" + colIndex+" "+s);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
ShowEmployee frame = new ShowEmployee();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The error happens because rowIndex and colIndex are -1 because there is no selection done. And there is nothing selected because you are calling `changeValue()` in the constructor for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling the `changeValue()` on form load itself and it always gives you rowIndx and columnIndex as -1 because nothing is selected on form load.

You can do it using `JButton's ActionListener` method. As you want to print the selected data just add a `button` called `print`.You can use ActionListener on `print` button.

Look at this example

```
public class TableValuePrint extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private final JButton print;
    private final JTable table;

    public TableValuePrint() {

        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Moni", "adsad", "Pass"},
            {"Jhon", "ewrewr", "Fail"},
            {"Max", "zxczxc", "Pass"}
        };

        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.add(tableSP);
        tablePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        add(tablePanel);
        setTitle("Result");

        setSize(1000,700);

        print=new JButton("Print");  
        JPanel jpi1 = new JPanel();  
        jpi1.add(print);  
        tablePanel.add(jpi1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);      

        print.addActionListener(this);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                TableValuePrint ex = new TableValuePrint();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       if(ae.getSource()==print){
         int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
         int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
         String s=(String) table.getValueAt(rowIndex,colIndex);
         System.out.println("INNERTABLE:" + rowIndex + "*" + colIndex+" "+s);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**OUTPUT :**

[image: output]

```
INNERTABLE:0*1 adsad
INNERTABLE:2*2 Pass
INNERTABLE:1*1 ewrewr
INNERTABLE:2*0 Max
```

Comment: -1 a mouselistener has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: still no good, same error as OP. Guys, why don't you simply test your "solutions" before posting? There's even a SSCCE to play with (okay, you would have to mock the data init, but that's not a big deal, simply use static data)

Comment: @Jugadu: no need to take button to print data.. just use Mouseclick Listener.. check my Answer

Comment: unselect the row and see what happens ... (that's the whole point of the problem, as you noticed yourself ;-)

Comment: @CiMat why did you accept this? Still has exactly the same error as your code ...

Comment: @kleopatra You mean to say that without selecting any row just press the print button?

Answer (score 0):

you have Error on this line `String s=(String) table.getValueAt(rowIndex,colIndex);`

USE my Update Answer You can get data where you click on perticular row..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowEmployee extends JFrame {

public JTable table = new JTable();

public ShowEmployee()
{
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<>();
    Connection cd = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        cd = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:tablename.sqlite");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) cd.prepareStatement("select name from table");
        pstmt.execute();
        ResultSet rs1 = pstmt.getResultSet();

        ResultSetMetaData md = rs1.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        // Get column names

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
        }

        // Get row data

        while (rs1.next()) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(rs1.getObject(i));
            }

            data.addElement(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null) {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //changeValue();

    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
      {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            try {
                printDebugData(table);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ShowEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData(JTable jTable1) throws ParseException
        {
              String selectedData = null;

            int numRows = jTable1.getRowCount();
            int numCols = jTable1.getColumnCount();
            int[] selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
            int[] selectedColumns = jTable1.getSelectedColumns();
            javax.swing.table.TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectedColumns.length; j++) 
                {
                    selectedData = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow[i], selectedColumns[j]);
                }
                System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
            }
        }
        });

  }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShowEmployee frame = new ShowEmployee();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
 }
```

Thanks..

Comment: -1 for just reproducing the same error .. (and a mouseListener is unrelated)

Comment: @kleopatra:but I just give hint how to get row,column value not copy,paste code and then run the code.. integration is upon OP.. then how do you say that reproducing same error?

Comment: @kleopatra: can you reconsider your vote? after checking my update answer?

Comment: repeating: the mouseListener doesn't make sense here (hint: the problem arises in the _unselected_ state)

Comment: @dic19: sorry it was by mistake to write NPE but I have solution.. and using this solution they get what they wanted??

Comment: Downvote revoked. I think your solution could work but not sure if it's what OP wants: *I want to select a row and column of jtable's cell and print the value...*. At this point I don't know if OP wants to select a cell by code and print its value or print the value every time a cell is selected (there's a slight difference). Anyway your solution prints **all** selected cells every time a mouse event is fired so it doesn't fit requirements entirely. You should also explain why OP is getting that error (*unselected* state).

Comment: @dic19: no he want the same as I give into the answer. That's why he accept the answer which is same as me.. but its not feasible as my answer.. in accepted answer everytime after selecting row that must click on mouse button to print.. and in my solution no need to click button.. get values in console at the same moment..